# Uploading JSON data to WordPress WPD3

Tags: wordpress, d3.js

I am using the WordPress WPD3 plugin - works fine with .csv and .tsv files, but will not upload .json data files - says it's for security reasons.  Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Just load your .json file with a .txt suffix, but refer to it as .json... as in

d3.json("data.txt", function(error, json) {
if (error) throw error;